# How can I search for and run a TestNG test method by the value of its annotation using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, integration-testing, testng

I am working on automated tests using Selenium WebDriver, Maven, and TestNG, and have come up with a seemingly unique problem. I would  like to run a test method by the value of an annotation attached to it, using Maven.

Background: We use TestRail for a test case management tool. TestRail assigns a unique case ID to every test case. It also has some functions for UI scripting to add functionality. I would like to be able to click a button in the TestRail UI and execute a test case(s).

I'm setting up Maven for our Selenium project, and it already has the ability to run a particular method of a particular test class, across my pool of test classes.

I have already set up a system where an @TestCaseID (value="12345") annotation is added to test methods, which is then picked up by a TestListener and used to send results back into TestRail.

The flow of operation would be this:

1. User locates test in TestRail
2. User clicks button
3. Some small program handles issuing a command to Maven, asking to run a particular test class and particular test annotation. (If I could skip the test class part and just go through all tests looking for that annotation, that would be nice!)
4. Something internal to Maven figures out which test method has the proper annotation, and then runs that test.

It occurs to me that perhaps this could be much easier to do if I forgot about the @TestCaseID annotation, and just included the case number in the test method name. That way, a pattern would be able to find and execute it. The annotations seem like a clean way to mark up test methods with their corresponding case IDs, but they aren't essential for anything.

What would be a good way to accomplish this task?

**EDIT**: To actually solve this problem for my project, I have decided that I have answered my own question and will not try to run a test based on annotation values. I'll just mark up my method names, which lets me do something fun in maven like "mvn verify -Dit.test=*#*12345".

Comment: Nice question.. I also want to know answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is "`mvn -Dtest=*#*12345 test`". as answered by you.

Other way is to add the test case id to the groups. and then run it using `mvn test -Dgroups=12345`

Groups will help to run Suites/User-Story/Feature as well.